# Загрузить html страницу сайта и найти в ней элементы по XPath без Selenium & etc

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

Могу ли я как-либо без использования Selenium и т.п. вещей (соответственно без открытия браузера), загрузить html страницу, т.е. полностью дождаться отработки на ней всех ajax запросов и т.п.
Если да, то какой наиболее эффективный способ потом ее распарсить, XPath?
По возможности, приведите примеры.
Благодарю!

Comment: то есть ты хочешь получить браузер без браузера но с браузером (для обработки ajax) )))) Здесь 2 выхода - или ты используешь селениум + phantomJS или же ты обрабатываешь все ajax запросы вручную. Выбирай)

Comment: @Andrew так я и не знаю, можно ли так сделать... Потому и спрашиваю. Может есть какой-то функционал, чтобы дождаться полной загрузки страницы... Как вариант конечно, просто запускать селениум и скрывать окно браузера и вебдрайвера. Но может есть что-то поэлегантней?))

Comment: если сайт с аджакс запросами - то самый элегантный - имитировать каждый из запросов вручную. Эт не на столько сложно.

Comment: Используйте `HttpClient` для скачивания данных странички и `HtmlAgilityPack` для парсинга HTML. Если нужно выполнение JS скрптов, то есть вместо `HtmlAgilityApck` можно использовать `AngleSharp` и его модуль `AngleSharp.JS`. Искать элементы и по XPath и CSS селектором оба пакета умеют.